# Bootstrap modal: event.relatedTarget (not updating)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap modal in which I want to update the appearance of the button that launched the modal.  The 'relatedTarget' does not appear to update when a new button launches the modal.

[Here's the Codepen](http://codepen.io/trinzia/pen/ozWVRE)

To reproduce the issue:

1. Click first button to launch modal.  Use radio button to apply a class to button.  Close modal.
2. Click second button to launch modal.  Use radio button to apply different class to second button.  Close modal.

[Issue]: Both buttons get the same class.  The first button will also change color.

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

   var origin = $(e.relatedTarget);  

   $("#modalButton").click( origin, updateButton );
    function updateButton (event) {   
        var color = $('input[name="radio_color"]:radio').filter(':checked').val()
        var origin = event.data;
        origin.removeClass('blue').removeClass('red').addClass(color); 
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }
});
```

Thanks so much for any help resolving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you haven't unbound your previous click event (so they are just stacking up - so the second click will fire 2 events - the new one and the previously bound one)

Add this:

```
$("#modalButton").off('click');
```

Before you bind the new click and it should solve your problem

[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/amWxQj)

Comment: Thanks - I was never going to find that solution on my own!